# How to specify constraint name in TypeOrm for postgresql

Tags: typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I would like to follow SQL naming standards for Primary and Foreign Key names.
One such approach is in [Naming conventions in SQL](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f0b2ed/what-is-naming-convention/).
For the Primary key, the name should be in the format PK_. The PrimaryGeneratedColumn decorator should allow you to enter the name.
For Foreign Key, the name should be in the format FK__. This could be in the relation decorator.

I cannot see how to achieve this.

Currently the constraints names do not have any semantic meaning - FK_f38670e509f911de73d91cab5bb

Could you let me know if there is another way to achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use @Unique() constraint as follows:

```
@Entity()
@Unique('UNIQUE_EMAIL_ADDRESS', ['address'])
export class Email {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 64 })
  address: string;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the issue is not with naming custom indices but the auto-generated ones such as primary key and foreign key constraints as given in the example. It just doesn't seem to be an option with TypeORM.

Answer (score 4):

- For primary key:

  ```
  @PrimaryColumn('uuid', { primaryKeyConstraintName: 'custom' })
  id: string;
  ```
- For foreign key:

  ```
  @ManyToOne(() => Currency, {})
  @JoinColumn({
  name: 'currencyId',
  referencedColumnName: 'id',
  foreignKeyConstraintName: 'custom',
  })
  currency: Currency;
  ```
- For unique key:

  ```
  @Unique('custom', ['username'])
  @Column({ length: 200 })
  username: string;
  ```

Comment: For anyone not seeing these options: they were just added in [v0.3.7](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/compare/0.3.6%E2%80%A60.3.7) (June 2022). If you don't have that version, your other option is a [custom naming strategy](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1355#issuecomment-660013778).

Comment: @Paul , I am working with version 0.2.29. When I add custom naming strategies some constrains renames correctly some don't. I noted that primary keys never renamed according to the naming strategy. Do you have any clue why it happens?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foreignKeyConstraintName` to specify constraint name

```
@JoinColumn([{ name: "user_id", referencedColumnName: "id", foreignKeyConstraintName: "fkey_constraint_name"}])
```